# Grails render template is not responding correctly

Tags: ajax, grails

I am using Grails 2.4.3. I have an ajax call to get a list of object. The list is ok. It has 10 elements. The problem is that when I want to send the list with model it is not behaving correctly. Nothing is generated in g:each block in my template although I have 10 records.

Here are my attempts below.

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:{id: 1},
        url:'/mdNote/getCareTopicTemplate/',
        success:function(data,textStatus){
            $modal.find('.modal-body').empty().append(data);
            $modal.find('.modal-title').empty().append(cfg.title);
            $modal.modal('show');
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){},
        complete:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){}
    });
```

My controller action:

```
def getCareTopicTemplate() {
    def careTopicList = mdNoteService.careTopicList()
    render(template: '/md/patient/existingTemplateRadioDiv', model: [careTopicList: careTopicList])
}
```

My template:

```
<div class="row" id="existingTemplateRadioDiv">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        Hello , this is outer text.
        <g:each in="${careTopicList}" var="careTopicList" status="i">
            this is inner text.
        </g:each>
    </div>
</div>
```

My list in IDE console:

[image]

In my view page after render template:

[image]

Comment: Try changing the name you're giving `var` in your `<g:each>` tag. You're telling it to use the same variable you're already iterating over. Like `<g:each in="${careTopicList}" var="careTopic" status="i">`

Comment: @doelleri you are genius. it works. how to take it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the name you're giving `var` in your `<g:each>` tag. You're telling it to use the same variable, `careTopicList`, that you're already iterating over. Something like the below should do the trick.

```
<g:each in="${careTopicList}" var="careTopic" status="i">
```